# AngularJS: Initialize nested scope variables in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I like to keep my namespace of model names clean and descriptive, so I use nested model variables like this (where month and year are nested in service):

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()">
  <select data-ng-model="service.month" data-ng-options="m for m in months"/>
  <input data-ng-model="service.year"/> {{ service.year }}
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And in my controller, I want to set `$scope.service.month` and `$scope.service.year` to initial values, but I get a javascript error `Cannot set property 'year' of undefined`, so I'm guessing the DOM hasn't been parsed and all the `$scope` variables haven't been created yet. How can I have some code wait to run until the DOM has been parsed by Angular and all the models have been created?

Here's my controller:

```
mod.controller('AddServiceCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    '$rootScope', 
function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var date = new Date();
  $scope.months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  $scope.service.year = 2014;   
  $scope.submit = function(){
  };
}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $scope.service= {month:'Mar',year:2014};
```

AngularJS is still JavaScript.

The AngularJS team unfortunately chose to name what is actually a presenter (or a view model), a `controller`. It might not sound that important, but conceptually it is in order to understand what `controllers` do.

Comment: alternatively he can do `$scope.service = {}`, then do things like `$scope.service.foo = bar`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `$scope.service` object is `undefined`, so it is failing to define a `year` property on it inside the controller, not the view.  To make this work, you must set `service` object on the scope like this:

```
$scope.service = {};
```

then you can define default values for the model on the controller **or** in the view:

**Controller option**

```
$scope.service = {};
$scope.service.year = 2014;
```

or

```
$scope.service = {
    year: 2014,
    month: $scope.months[3]   // to default to 'Apr'
};
```

**View Option**

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()" 
      data-ng-init="service.year=2014; service.month=months[3]">
    ...
</form>
```

either way, you must create the `service` object on the scope in order to define properties thereon.  use object literal notation (`{}`) to create it.